# Binary/integer variables get real values in docplex

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, binary-variable, docplex

I have an MILP model, in which I am handling all *Big M* constraints with *add_if_then* constraints (following [this topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/why-does-binary-or-integer-variable-take-noninteger-value-solution)). I generate this model only once (to save time) and solve it iteratively with different coefficients of the objective function (I only update the objective function) - coded via docplex in Python.

After some iterations, the binary/integer variables get real values (the optimality gap is 5%). What would be the reason of this (other than having Big M constraints)? Unfortunately, I am unable to share the entire model with you. However, I can provide you with further information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All solution values will be floating-point numbers - independent of the variable types. In an optimal or feasible solution, they will simply be *close* to an integer value, depending on the specified tolerance. Usually, there is a numeric tolerance for small violations regarding the bounds and right hand sides and another one that is only concerned about the integrality of the solution.

Comment: Oh, I see. I just set *mdlS.parameters.mip.tolerances.integrality = 0*. I will report if the problem still exists.

Comment: Setting the integrality tolerance to zero is not without risk. In a model with tricky numerics (which can easily happen in a "big M" formulation), an integrality tolerance of zero can lead to suboptimal solutions or even a false claim of infeasibility.

Comment: @mdslt It's likely the binary/integer values you are seeing are very close to integers.  If you are concerned about feasibility, then re-solving with the almost-integer variable values fixed to their rounded integer values would confirm whether you have actually obtained a feasible solution